# Excel search multiples rows containing substring

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with 2 sheets :

- The first one got a list of keywords in a column.
- The second one got sentences on a column along with an id on another column.

Thus the 2 sheets look like this :

```
Sheet 1:                         Sheet 2:
   A                      A             B
| the |               | 15587 | The cat is walking |
| cat |               | 94683 | No one here        |
| ... |               | 47222 | The TV is on       |
                      | 59378 | No cat allowed     |
                      |  ...  | ...                |
```

What I want to do is to put on the B column of sheet 1 the list of sentences ids where the keyword is found. So here I'll get on sheet 1 :

```
   A         B
| the | 15587;47222 |
| cat | 15587;59378 |
| ... |     ...     |
```

Do you know how I can achieve this using functions ? I tried VLOOKUP but it only returns the first occurrence and I don't know how to use FILTER with an operator to check if the sentence contain a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",,FILTER(A$1:A$4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&D1&" "," "&B$1:B$4&" ")),""))
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's what I needed ! In case someone need it with keywords not separated by spaces in the sentences, you can use : `=TEXTJOIN(";",,FILTER(A$1:A$4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,B$1:B$4)),""))`. That's usefull in some cases where the sentences is "KEY1.KEY2.KEY3" and you search for "KEYn" elements for example.

Comment: @karzyfox. Not right, that would allow for false positives. Just concatenate the values with the dots instead of spaces.